# oledb diregarding parameters on sqlanywhere-db

Tags: c#, oledb, sqlanywhere

I have a `SqlContext` class which is implemented for SQL Server, MySql, Odbc and Oledb. It delivers basic functions like insert, update and delete. It worked all fine until I had to connect to a SqlAnywhere database. When I call update, I get an error which says the column is not found.

Here is my Odbc implementation for the update function:

```
public override int Update(string tableName, Action<ISqlParameterizer> actionSqlParameterizerUpdate, Action<ISqlParameterizer> actionSqlParameterizerWhere)
{
    var commandText = $"update {tableName} set @update where @where";

    var whereBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var updateBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var whereParameterizer = SqlParameterizer.CreateFrom(this);
    var updateParameterizer = SqlParameterizer.CreateFrom(this);

    actionSqlParameterizerWhere?.Invoke(whereParameterizer);
    actionSqlParameterizerUpdate?.Invoke(updateParameterizer);

    List<IDbDataParameter> parameterList = new List<IDbDataParameter>();

    foreach (var whereParameter in whereParameterizer.GetParameters())
    {
        whereBuilder.Append($" and {whereParameter.ParameterName} = @{whereParameter.ParameterName}");
        parameterList.Add(whereParameter);
    }

    foreach (var updateParameter in updateParameterizer.GetParameters())
    {
        updateBuilder.Append($", {updateParameter.ParameterName} = @{updateParameter.ParameterName}");
        parameterList.Add(updateParameter);
    }

    commandText = commandText.Replace("@where", whereBuilder.ToString().Substring(4));
    commandText = commandText.Replace("@update", updateBuilder.ToString().Substring(1));

    return base.ExecuteNonQuery(commandText, parameterList.ToArray());
}
```

I call it like this:

```
base.Source.Update("SOME_TABLE", set => 
{
    set.Add("ANWENDER_ID", anwender_id); //Store some FK in here
},where =>
{
    where.Add("user_name", user_name); //For a specific user (user_name is pk)
});
```

The exception message:

> ERROR [42S22] [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Spalte '@user_name' nicht gefunden

It says "column '@user_name' not found".

The `commandText` looks like this:

```
update SOME_TABLE set ANWENDER_ID = @ANWENDER_ID where user_name = @user_name
```

The parameters of my `SqlCommand` are filled correctly. Why does it say that the column is not found? The column exists and has the right name. When I copy the `commandText` and fill in the parameters, I can execute the query. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @parameter in your CommandText is not valid syntax for SQLAnywhere.

> Placeholders for parameters in SQL statements are indicated by the ? character. For any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE, each ? is referenced according to its ordinal position in the command's parameters collection. For example, the first ? is referred to as 0, and the second as 1.

So your CommandText needs to look like this:

```
update SOME_TABLE set ANWENDER_ID = ? where user_name = ?
```

Comment: Thats it. My implementation of OleDbSqlContext was having the logic for building the queries. But since the synthax for statements is termited by the target of the database my OleDbSqlContext is connecting, i made the OleDbSqlContext class abstract and made a implementation for every target-db-system.